# How do I check if a text column is empty or null with Prisma JS

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma

I am using Postgresql and Prisma as an ORM. I have a table with a text column and I have many rows in the table where the value of this column is null or empty.

Is there a special way to determine whether the value of a text column is null or empty ?

On sql i would do something like :

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn IS NULL OR myColumn = ''
```

Comment: Are you trying to query the null columns or including this logic in an update query?

Comment: I'm trying to query empty and/or null columns

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this with the Prisma client:

```js
const records = await prisma.record.findMany({
  where: {
    OR: [{ myColumn: null }, { myColumn: "" }],
  },
});
```

Comment: This returns null but not empty columns (value = '')

Comment: Ooo that is tricky. I will see what I can do.

Comment: Ok, maybe that update will work a bit better.